# Is it possible to use Ansible fetch and copy modules for SCPing files

Tags: yaml, ansible

Im trying to SCP a .sql file from one server to another, and I am trying to use an Ansible module to do so.  I stumbled across the fetch and copy modules, but I am not sure how to specify which host I want to copy the file from.

This is my current Ansible file:

`firstDB database dump happens on seperate host`

```
    - hosts: galeraDatabase
      become: yes
      remote_user: kday
      become_method: sudo

      tasks:
    - name: Copy file to the galera server
      fetch:
        dest: /tmp/
        src: /tmp/{{ tenant }}Prod.sql
        validate_checksum: yes
        fail_on_missing: yes
```

Basically, I want to take the dump file from the `firstDB` host, and then get it over to the other `galeraDatabase` host.  How would I do this?  Im order to use fetch or copy, I would need to pass it the second hostname to copy the files from, and I don't see any parameters to do that inside of the documentation.  Should I be using a different method altogether?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the synchronize module with delegate_to, or if you don't have rsync then use the copy module. Some [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505146/how-to-copy-files-between-two-nodes-using-ansible) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468350/ansible-copy-vs-synchronize) relating to this topic already on stackoverflow.

Also, check the ansible documentation for more info on the copy and synchronize modules along with the delegate_to tasks parameter.

hth.